# JMeter / Beanshell "Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file:"

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I'm having an issue in JMeter wherein I receive this error

```
2014/08/14 14:13:26 ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval   Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``String RequestUrl = vars.get("RequestUrl"); String[] params = RequestUrl.split(" . . . '' : Typed variable declaration 
2014/08/14 14:13:26 WARN  - jmeter.extractor.BeanShellPostProcessor: Problem in BeanShell script org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval   Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``String RequestUrl = vars.get("RequestUrl"); String[] params = RequestUrl.split(" . . . '' : Typed variable declaration
```

I have no clue whats wrong, and the code otherwise seems to be working. Can anyone give me some advice?

Here is the block of code in question:

```
String RequestUrl = vars.get("RequestUrl");
String[] params = RequestUrl.split("\\?");
String RequestTask = params[1].split("\\&")[1].split("=")[1];
System.out.println(RequestTask);
vars.put("RequestTask",RequestTask);
```

it should probably be mentioned that the code is in a post processor, which is paired with an Xpath extractor for "RequestUrl"

Edited to include entire error

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't see your URL and what does XPath query return but in any case your URL parsing logic looks flaky as it strongly dependent on parameters order and presence and may bite you back in future in case of request URL change i.e. extra parameter or changed parameters order or something encoded, etc.

See below for reference:

```
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.List;

String url = vars.get("RequestUrl");

List params = URLEncodedUtils.parse(new URI(url), "UTF-8");

for (NameValuePair param : params) {            
    if (param.getName().equals("put your actual param name here")) {                 
        vars.put("RequestTask", param.getValue());
    }
}
```

Also it worth checking out [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) for troubleshooting tips. In general to localize error logging should be used like:

```
log.info("something");
log.error("something else");
```

So if you don't see message in the log than Beanshell wasn't able to execute the line and failed somewhere above.

Also Beanshell error messages aren't very informative, I use the following construction in my scripts:

```
try {
    //script logic here
}

catch (Throwable ex) {
    log.error("Failed to do this or that", ex);
}
```

So error stracktrace could be read in jmeter.log file.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, this helps incredibly well! The only other question is, How would I get the raw URL from the http request to which this post processor is attached?(so that I might assign it to RequestURL) I'm not sure whether to use an XPath query extractor, or a RegEx extractor.. but either way I've yet to be successful in any kind of url extraction

Comment: It's as simple as `prev.getURL()` to get java.net.URL instance or `prev.getURL().toString()` for String representation.

Comment: Suggested debugging tip helped a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Could you show the whole error?

Try adding one statement after the other to see which one is root cause.

I suppose you may be making hypothesis on results (array access) which may be cause of issue.

Comment: not much more info, try following my advice and displaying intermediate results

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by your suggestion. Each line relies on the line before it to run, so I could not add one statement after the other without breaking it

Comment: No i meant, keep  first line and comment everything else, then un comment 2nd line (so only lines 1 & 2 are not commented...

Comment: Oh, I see. Regardless, I've narrowed it down to the XPath Extractor. I think its simply coming down to having the wrong path for the query. Will update with progress

Answer (score 0):

if you are coverting a VuGen recorded JMS script to JMeter, then you have to look for the `lr` functions copied which WILL throw this/similar error.

For eg: `int orderlinecount = Integer.parseInt(lr.eval_string("strInt"));`

You have to make sure your script is free of all lr - related functions in order for the jmeter to successfully executed your script.